# How can i overwrite the dictionary key names in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have this code for replacing the keys from another dictionary

```
def overwriteKeys(data, type=2):
        d = (
            ('user1', 'user11'),
            ('user2', 'user21'),
            ('user3', 'user31'),
            ('user4', 'user1'),
            ('user5', 'user51'),
        )

        d = collections.OrderedDict(d)


        data1 = data.copy()

        for k1 in data:
            for k2 in d:
                if k1 == k2:
                    key = d[k2]
                    data1[key] = data[k1]
                    del data1[k1]
        return data1
```

Currently it replaces the key with value. But i want that if `type=1` then it should replace the the other way  , `value with key`. Also i am looking for some short code

EDIT:

```
d = {
    "user1" : "john"
    "user2" : "tom"   
}

will become

d = {
    "user11" : "john"
    "user21" : "tom"   
}
```

and if type = 1  then

```
d = {
    "user11" : "john"
    "user2" : "tom"   
}

will become

d = {
    "user1" : "john"
    "user2" : "tom"   
}
```

Comment: Can you give us a sample of the data you pass in and what you want as the result? Sorry, but I am confused by the description.

Comment: What Python version are you using?

Comment: @JonClements i am using python 3

Comment: @RobertB , i have added the output

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking.  Can you provide an example of what `data` would be and what `data1` should look like after the transformation.

Comment: So in your `type=1` case your instead keying by the `value`, and `value` is unique in the data set?

Comment: @monkut the value is unique

Comment: If `value` is unique, have you considered keying by the `value` instead?

Comment: @monkut i didn't get that

Comment: Your second example is incorrect right? 'user2' doesn't exist on the right side, so for type 2 it is a key error.

Comment: @RobertB if key does not exist then it should stay as it is

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> t2 = dict([
...         ('user1', 'user11'),
...         ('user2', 'user21'),
...         ('user3', 'user31'),
...         ('user4', 'user1'),
...         ('user5', 'user51'),
...     ])
>>> 
>>> d = {
...     "user1": "john",
...     "user2" : "tom"   
... }
>>> 
>>> {t2.get(k, k): v for k, v in d.items()}
{'user11': 'john', 'user21': 'tom'}
```

You can create a dict for the reverse transformation like this

```
t1 = {v: k for k, v in t2.items()}
```

SO finally you get something like

```
def overwriteKeys(data, type=2):
    t2 = dict([
        ('user1', 'user11'),
        ('user2', 'user21'),
        ('user3', 'user31'),
        ('user4', 'user1'),
        ('user5', 'user51'),
    ])

    t1 = {v: k for k, v in t2.items()}
    t = t1 if type == 1 else t2
    return {t.get(k, k): v for k, v in data.items()}
```

To preserve the order in the case that `data` is an `OrderedDict`

```
    return OrderedDict((t.get(k, k), v) for k, v in data.items())
```

Comment: Seems a waste to create `t1` if it's not required

Comment: @JonClements, of course. I just did it this way for clarity.  `t = {v: k for k, v in t2.items()} if type == 1 else t2` doesn't seem as clear

Comment: will t1 , t2 be ordered , i want ordered dict

Comment: do you mean the `data` is an ordered dict? You can make the output in the same order as `data` in that case. I will add to my answer

Comment: @JohnLaRooy not data but `t2`  suppose we chnage `user1` to `user11` then we have mapping  `user4` to `user1` . then that `user1` will also get converted to `user11`  .

Comment: The substitutions are carried out on the original data, so only one substitution can happen per key. I Think that is what you want

Answer (score 2):

You're not actually "overwriting" anything in your original example - so, you can build a new dict that uses a looked up value if possible, otherwise it uses the original. As for a reverse look up - reverse the elements of the tuple before building a `dict`, eg:

```
def change_keys(data, type=2):
    d = (
        ('user1', 'user11'),
        ('user2', 'user21'),
        ('user3', 'user31'),
        ('user4', 'user1'),
        ('user5', 'user51'),
    )

    if type == 1:
        d = tuple(el[::-1] for el in d)

    return {d.get(k, k):v for k, v in OrderedDict(d).items()}
```

Example:

```
d = {"user1" : "john", "user2" : "tom"}
print(change_keys(d), change_keys(d, 1))
# {'user11': 'john', 'user21': 'tom'} {'user4': 'john', 'user2': 'tom'}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to think about this is to have a separate dictionary where your values map to keys.

```
original_dict = {"a":"x", "b":"y"}
new_dict = {}
for k in original_dict:
    new_dict[original_dict[k]]=k
```

Do your magic after! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
def overwriteKeys(data, type=2):
        d = (
            ('user1', 'user11'),
            ('user2', 'user21'),
            ('user3', 'user31'),
            ('user4', 'user1'),
            ('user5', 'user51'),
        )

        d = collections.OrderedDict(d)
        if type == 2:
            d = collections.OrderedDict([(value, key) for key, value in d.iteritems()])


        data1 = data.copy()

        for k1 in data:
            for k2 in d:
                if k1 == k2:
                    key = d[k2]
                    data1[key] = data[k1]
                    del data1[k1]
        return data1
```

Comment: Thanks i think that will work . is there shorter way of doing that  . i mean using some  map reduce etc .

Comment: well, you don't actually need the ordered dict.  
`d = dict(map(lambda k: (d[k], k), d))`, it's a little more terse, but harder to read, and good python form favors easier-to-read over terseness.

Comment: I needed ordered dict because user1 is replaced with user11 but user4 is replaced with user1 . if they are not in order then that will aslo get replaced

Comment: @user3214546 as long as the keys are unique in both directions - I don't see how that's a concern - a mapping only occurs once... it won't chain.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Fixed so that missing items remain:

```
def overwriteKeys(data, type=2):
    d = {
    'user1': 'user11',
    'user2': 'user21',
    'user3': 'user31',
    'user4': 'user1',
    'user5': 'user51',
    }
    if type==2:
       d = { d[key] : key for key in d }

    new_dict = { d[old_key] : data[old_key] for old_key in data if old_key in d }
    new_dict.update({ old_key : data[old_key] for old_key in data if old_key not in d })

    return new_dict
```